# EF Core : Update column only for modified properties from disconnected entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1 with SQL Server.

I search how update column only for modified properties of a disconnected entity like :

```cs
public void UpdateOrderCustomer(int orderId, string customerName)
{
    var order = new Order { Id = orderId };

    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        context.Update(order);
        order.Customer = customerName;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But this updates all order's column.

One solution is to load entity before update properties like :

```cs
public void UpdateOrderCustomer(int orderId, string customerName)
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var order = context.Orders.Single(o => o.Id == orderId);
        order.Customer = customerName;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But to load the entity, this executes an additional useless query.

I hoped there would be a `BeginTracking` method, but I haven't found this or any similar functionality.

How to update columns only for modified properties from a disconnected entity?

Comment: I think you're asking for something that's fundamentally impossible. Consider this: you're loading a given entity from the database at some point in time, then you're sending it to a remote client. There could be quite some time passed, before that client sends back that disconnected entity - EF cannot possibly "hang on" to tracking information for that long - so it knows **nothing** about how that data looked like when you loaded it a while ago. How on earth should it be able to figure out what has changed? Reloading now and comparing is the only viable way to go ....

Comment: I understands and it's that I do in most case. But some times you just want update 1 column without care the state of the row. I agree, it's micro-optimisation question.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you might be able to attach the entity and mark the columns for that you want to update as modified. `context.Attach(customer);`
`context.Entry(customer).Property("FirstName").IsModified = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a single property or a deattached entity like so:

```
public void ChangePassword(int userId, string password)
{
  var user = new User() { Id = userId, Password = password };
  using (var db = new MyEfContextName())
  {
    db.Users.Attach(user);
    db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: This work, but I will prefer a solution will use the tracker. I will accept this answer if none better solution is posted.

Comment: @Vernou, I don't know of one.  The main benefit of this is you don't need to load the entity into memory from the DB first